# Where is 'value' in 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm looking to shorten this code down:

```
for i in card.get_mana_cost():
    if i is 'W' and colors[0] is not 0:
        match_colors = True
    elif i is 'U' and colors[1] is not 0:
        match_colors = True
    elif i is 'B' and colors[2] is not 0:
        match_colors = True
    elif i is 'R' and colors[3] is not 0:
        match_colors = True
    elif i is 'G' and colors[4] is not 0:
        match_colors = True
```

The best way I can think of is to put my chars in a list like `symbols = ['W', 'U', 'B', 'R', 'G']`
and then the index I want to reach in colors will always be the same as the index for symbols, but I don't know how to check which index triggered `in` to return `True`.

I tried using `zip` to create a dictionary with `[symbols: colors]` but I still need to find the index so I check the right value is not 0.

**Edit**

`card.get_mana_cost()` returns a list of string of varied size. Usually it will only hold 2 or 3 elements in it.

Also, I really don't like using nested loops, I find they become hard to read and debug after just short breaks from the code and they easily use a lot of space and time. I won't have long lists to go through, but I might have a lot of cards, so if there's a simple alternative, I'd rather use that.

Comment: what is `card.get_mana_cost()` in your code?

Comment: It's a list of varying length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified to this.

```
char_list = ['W', 'U', 'B', 'R', 'G']
for i in card.get_mana_cost():
    match_colors = i in char_list and color[char_list.index(i)] is not 0
```

The important thing here is `char_list.index`. It returns the index of `i` in `char_list`.

Comment: `card.get_mana_cost()` will probably be shorter than the `char_list`. I probably should have mentioned that, but `.index` is something I'll be reading up on.
Thanks

Comment: @Maxia The length of `get_mana_cost` does not matter here, right?

Comment: @Maxia By the way, if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: If card.get_mana_cost() has 3 elements in it, then wouldnt `i in char_list` only ever be able to check up to `'B'`?
Unless `i` is an element, not a counter, which seems more pythonic.

Comment: @Maxia `in` just checks whether `i` is in the list. `i` _is_ an element.